# Deleting nodes recursively

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have created this function to recursively delete nodes from a doubly linked list. The issue here is that based on the call stack, it starts from the second so it does not delete the entire list. I can delete the remaining node from the method where I'm calling this but there should be a way around that. Is there a way of resolving this issue?

```
    void RecursiveClear(const Node* _curr) {
    if(_curr != nullptr) {
        //_curr->prev = _curr;
        _curr = _curr->next;
        RecursiveClear(_curr);
    }
    if (_curr != nullptr) {
        delete _curr;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to start from the second node, why is the first thing you do to advance your pointer to the second node? It's doing exactly what you told it to. If you want it to do something else, then tell it to do _that_ instead. This is probably a good time to learn how to use a debugger, so you can see & understand exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: Good point Useless. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: Don't use a leading `_`.

You modify `_curr` in the function so by the time you end up at the `delete` the original pointer is gone. So don't do that, just call the function wiht the next value without modifying the local vbariable:

```
RecursiveClear(_curr->next);
```

You also shouldn't do a recursion like that because lists can be long. Your code is not tail recursive. Every node in the list will use up a little bit of stack space. For long lists this will overflow the stack and crash.

Use a temporary so you can reorder the operations to be tail recursive:

```
void RecursiveClear(const Node* curr) {
   if (curr != nullptr) {
        const Node *next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        RecursiveClear(next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Goswin. This makes perfect sense. The only change I had to do was RecursiveClear(_curr->next) to RecursiveClear(_curr) otherwise it wouldn't do as it should. Appreciate your quick answer.

Comment: A better option is to simply not use recursion at all, use an iterative loop instead, which is much safer, eg: `void IterativeClear(const Node* curr) { while (curr != nullptr) { const Node *next = curr->next; delete curr; curr = next; } }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I assumed this is the same exercise as other questions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks Remy. I already knew how to do it what way. I just wanted to try to implement the recursive way also.